# How to convert PDF to TIFF format?

Tags: python, pdf, tiff

Here is my code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


images = convert_from_path('resume.pdf', 500, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-22.11.0\Library\bin')

for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.tiff', 'TIFF')
```

Tiff is a format which may contain many images for example one TIFF file can contain 3 pages.
I've got pages, but i want to collect all pages in one file, how to do this?

Ive tried to use third-party libraries but I guess I didn't find the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save them all as one file rather than giving each page a distinct name:

```
images[0].save('result.tif', save_all =True, append_images = images[1:])
```

---

You'll probably want to add `compression='tiff_lzw'` as a parameter, otherwise you'll get an enormous, uncompressed TIFF.

See the Pillow documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#), section entitled **TIFF**.